# Assemble random sales table with Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have attempted to assemble a randomized sales table with mock data.

- I have a customer table with 50,000 entries.
- I have a product table with 550,000 entries.
- I produced a series with store codes. Ideally I'd like 5 stores.
- I also created a date/time series spanning 2 years.
- I would love to create a mock sales table that gives me at least 500K sales lines per year.
- The end result would be exported to CSV.

Ideally, this would give me output as follows, basically mimicking a true sales table:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| CustomerID | FirstName | LastName | ProductName | ProductID | StoreID |  Date   |
+------------+-----------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+
|     157863 | Kimberly  | Archey   | Name1       | ID1       |       1 | 1/1/22  |
|     148101 | Tony      | Roberson | Name2       | ID2       |       2 | 1/5/23  |
|     113579 | Mandy     | Kridel   | Name3       | ID3       |       3 | 1/4/22  |
|      23000 | Russell   | Cornett  | Name4       | ID4       |       4 | 1/3/22  |
|     160104 | Craig     | Sterling | Name5       | ID5       |       5 | 1/10/22 |
+------------+-----------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

I found an article online that explained how to create a mock sales table, however, I think my data is too complex. The following code crashes the kernel:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
   [date_range_2022, store_codes, df3['ProductID'], df_customers['CustomerID']],
   names = ['Date', 'StoreCode', 'ProductID', 'CustomerID'])

sales = pd.DataFrame(index = index)

sales.head()
```

It works OK if I am just combining the time series and store codes, but if I add in other fields, it bombs.

I have not been able to figure out how to generate a sales table from the data I already have.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Isn't it a cartesian product between all the inputs? I'd create a first `sales_df` then expand it by merging with other dataframes.

Comment: I thought about that, however, I don't want an end result that lists all possible combinations. I want it to be truly random, like a real-life sales table would be. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not getting random data from the `df_customers` and then join with other dataframes (for each table)? My guess for starting `df_customers.sample(1000)`.

Comment: Let me try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `np.random.choice`?
Something like this is a very minimal example on how you could make it work. It gives you 100 rows randomly filled with values from your example data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n_sales = 100

sample_data = dict(
    products = ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    store = [1,2,3,4,5]
)

df_data = {column: np.random.choice(values, n_sales) for column, values in sample_data.items()}

pd.DataFrame(data=df_data, index=range(rows))
```

If you want to use the columns with your sample data directly you can access and combine them into a dataframe like this:

```
sales_dates = pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2023-12-31', freq='H')
sales = pd.DataFrame({
    'CustomerID': np.random.choice(df_customers['CustomerID'], size=n_sales),
    'ProductID': np.random.choice(df_products['ProductID'], size=n_sales),
    'Date': np.random.choice(sales_dates, size=n_sales),
})
```

Comment: Oddly enough, the other person's answer - since deleted - worked for me. I tried yours and tweaked it as best as I could, but it errors out. Could you please revise to reflect the following: I have these data frames: df_customers, df_products, df_stores (converted from the store series); date_range is a date/time series. My goal is to end up with roughly 500K rows of random sales data. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since the other answer was taken directly from ChatGPT, you are free to use it as well. Just paste in your question and receive the answer

Comment: I'd like to use yours, since that was legitimate? There's a reason they deleted it, but I tried it anyway. If you could revise it accordingly so I can give you appropriate credit? I tried to tweak it, but I got errors. I haven't been working long with Python.

Comment: PS. If I wanted to use ChatGPT, I would. But the code it spits out is usually garbage - there's a reason it's banned here. They got lucky, but I would not have marked it as the right answer either way.

Comment: Sure, I can understand that. I would need to know what the errors are that you get, so I can help you though

Comment: So, here is the code. I apologize up front for what I did to it: ```import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rows = 500000

data = dict(
    products = df_products,
    store = df_stores,
    customers = df_customers,
    dates = date_range
)

df_sales = {column: np.random.choice(values, rows) for column, values in data.items()}

pd.DataFrame(data=df_sales, index=range(rows))```

Comment: And here is the error that produces: ```13 df_sales = {column: np.random.choice(values, rows) for column, values in data.items()}
     14 
     15 pd.DataFrame(data=df_sales, index=range(rows))

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.choice()

ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional```

Comment: I updated the answer to show how you can work with dataframes directly

Comment: That worked! You omitted `'Store': np.random.choice(store_codes, size=n_sales)`, but I added that in w/o issue. Thank you!